# using std::is_base_of in static_assert fails due to incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static-assert

What I am trying to do is have some classes inherit form an `extention` class. The thing is the `extention` class has to know which class it is extending.

This can simply be achieved like this:

```
template<typename Self>
class Extention
{
    public:
        void check() const
        {
            std::cout << "Extention is valid: "
                      << std::boolalpha
                      << std::is_base_of<Extention, Self>::value
                    << std::endl;
        }
};
class Foo : public Extention<Foo> {};
class Bar : public Extention<void> {};
```

The `Foo` and `Bar` class show good, and bad usage of the extention.

```
Foo().check(); → Extention is valid: true
Bar().check(); → Extention is valid: false
```

I would like to check the validity of the template during compilation, which brought me to write

```
template<typename Self>
class Extention
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Extention, Self>::value);
};
```

However, gcc tels me this `static_assert` is wrong as `class Foo` has incomplete type.

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: I'm using `-std=c++17`, error is not the lack of error message in the `static_assert`

Comment: You could put `static_assert` into a member function, but for it to work you have to instantinate the function (possibly by calling it).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat putting it in the constructor would work. Still, it would be painfull and error prone if you have multiple constructor...

Comment: Rather than hitting all your constructors with static asserts, is deriving template `Extention` from a protected `Requiredived` is `Self` an option? That would give you a root protected default constructor, `RequiredBase()`, in which to hang your static assert. Or maybe I misunderstood your goal here.

Comment: Then how about putting it into the destructor?

Comment: @WhozCraig: would work but fells over-engineered. HolyBlackCat: would work and fells more elegant.
Still, we should be able to put the assertion directly into the class ...

Comment: @Amxx I tend to avoid introducing non-default destructors unless it's necessary. That's the only reason I mentioned a construction alternative. Someone can easily (and incorrectly) write code that does *not* fire a proper non-virtual destruction chain, but construction is pretty much unavoidable. Regardless, that the standard library and language don't work as you would like is usually just a point where you either have to (a) reconsider how you're designing something, or (b) find a work-around, ideally in that order. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong ?

Because of [[meta.rel]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.rel), `std::is_base_of` requires that the derived type is a complete type:

> If `Base` and `Derived` are non-union class types and are not possibly cv-qualified versions of the same type, `Derived` shall be a complete type.

On the other side, [[class.mem/6]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6) states that:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier. [...]

That isn't your case. When you instantiate `Extension<Foo>`, `Foo` itself is far from being completely-defined.

In other terms, you cannot use that `static_assert` at the class scope. Put it in the destructor's body (my preferred solution actually, even though it has a few drawbacks) or any other (special) member method's body if you prefer.